# MongoDB: Not authorized on database to execute command eval

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database-administration, rbac

This is the query i am running:

```
db.surveyquestion.copyTo('surveyquestionV2')
```

Error I am getting:

```
{
    "message" : "MongoError: not authorized on GenericSurveyTool to execute command { $eval: function (collName, newName) {\r" +
              "var from = db[collName];\r" +
              "..., args: [ 'surveyquestion', 'surveyquestionV2' ], $db: 'GenericSurveyTool' }",
    "stack" : "script:1:19",
    "code" : 13
}
```

My user in admin db that i am using to run this query:

```
query:  db.getUsers();


/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "admin.moiz",
    "user" : "moiz",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this user with the root role but still i am unable to copy collection. Please help!!

Comment: Try with `dbOwner` instead of root in your roles array

Comment: Its not working, same issue persists.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you authenticate as moiz before launch query ?

Comment: Yes, thats for sure

Comment: I've just seen that in the documentation of the db.eval() command : `If authorization is enabled, you must have access to all actions on all resources in order to run eval. Providing such access is not recommended, but if your organization requires a user to run eval, create a role that grants anyAction on anyResource. Do not assign this role to any other user.`

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas that worked for me. There is build in role called __system in mongo db. I granted this role to my user. And It worked fine. Please add it as an answer that would help others in future.

Comment: No problem ! Don't forget to validate the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the people who has the same problem, the solution is in the documentation of `db.eval()` : [just right here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/index.html)

> If authorization is enabled, you must have access to all actions on all resources in order to run eval. Providing such access is not recommended, but if your organization requires a user to run eval, create a role that grants anyAction on anyResource. Do not assign this role to any other user.

Comment: There really isn't much here other than a quote from the documentation, so I'm really not sure it should be an answer. The biggest problem with the response is that it does not highlight that `eval` is in fact deprecated and due for removal from MongoDB altogether, and therefore it is not wise for anyone to be writing current code which uses it as their code will simply cease to work, This is actually spelled out within the documentation. As are various other warnings which really should be at the forefront of any response.